# How to get Selenium to recognise a button and click it?

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How would I get selenium python to recognise this button in HTML?

I've tried this and other tags to get it

```py
 driver.find_element_by_class_name('cookie-monster').clickbutton
        print('button was clicked')
```

This is the button snippet code

```
<button class="cookie-monster__cta cookie-monster__cta--primary js-cookie-monster-accept">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
Accept All Cookies
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locator is wrong. The class is named `cookie-monster__cta`, not .`cookie-monster`. `js-cookie-monster-accept` seems to be unique class name. Use it for finding your element.
Also, you should wait for elements before clicking them.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "js-cookie-monster-accept")))
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("js-cookie-monster-accept")
button.click()
```

If this locator is not unique, add classes one by one to both `wait` and `find_element_by_css_selector`, like this:

```
.js-cookie-monster-accept.cookie-monster__cta
```

Comment: If this works, please accept the answer or inform if some other issue will occur.

Comment: Hi, its now coming up with an error say that wait is not defined. So i Put `Webdriverwait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(`

However its saying that `selectby` is not defined.

Comment: Change selectby to By and add import from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Comment: Throwing up this message now, not clicking the button either.
 
`File "C:\Users\danin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: Add wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20). I thought you were already using it.

Comment: Hi, i could not get it to work, so i ended up using xpath to find the element and it worked better, thanks anyway though.

Comment: The xpath that you proposed will break sooner or later. I will check and add a better one later.

Comment: Ok, if my locator does not work yet, it mean that it is not unique. Can you check it in devtools? button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/button[2]") - This one may be unstable.If you want this way, for xpath better use //button[text() = 'Accept All Cookies']